# using BASH to find file duplicates and most recent

Tags: bash

If I have a directory containing files as such:

```
05_JIMMY_contents_20170608.txt
05_JIMMY_contents_20171019_EMPTY.txt
05_JIMMY_contents_20171020.txt
06a_SD_VIDEO_contents_20161102.txt
06b_SD_VIDEO_bk_contents_20161102.txt
07_MALCOLM_contents_20170222_EMPTY.txt
13_HOBSON_contents_20170615.txt
13_HOBSON_contents_20171019_EMPTY.txt
13_HOBSON_contents_20171020_EMPTY.txt
```

And I want to only keep one file of each number/name (05_Jimmy, for example) and I want that file to be the most recent one based on the date in the file name (20171020, for example), how do I determine if their are multiple files with the same number/name and then find which one has the most recent date using BASH?

Comment: Sort the list in reverse order, so the most recent one is first. Pipe this list through an `awk` script that adds `number/name` to an array. If it gets another line with an existing `number/name` in the array, it outputs an `rm` command for that filename.

Comment: @Barmar That sounds like it could work, but I'm not good with `awk` if you have an example script, great! Otherwise I'll dig around.

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: I would argue that https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/14122 is a slightly better guide in terms of what kind of homework questions are allowed (basically, we'll answer questions that come out of homework if they're sufficiently well-asked questions that they'd be inside site rules regardless). Note the guidelines, particularly the first two: **Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first**, and **Ask about *specific* problems with your *existing* implementation**.

Comment: ...anyhow, in terms of some hints / starting points: You might try to use regexes (search for `BASH_REMATCH` to find docs/guidance on bash's built-in regex support) to extract the specific pieces you want from the name. I'd also think about using an associative array to map each number/name pair to the most recent date yet found.

Comment: (Contrary to Barmar's initial suggestion, I'm **not at all** a fan of using `awk` to generate code -- easy to have security bugs, especially if you don't control your filenames; if someone runs `touch '05_JIMMY_contents_20170601_$(rm -rf ~).txt'` in a shared directory, you don't want your home directory being deleted when your script tries to remove that file).